# String to Money Data Type in SQL SERVER

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, parameters, sqlclient

I tried to insert a `STRING` from a `TextBox` to the `COLUMN` that has a `MONEY DATA TYPE` but an error prompt appeared and says : *Error Occured, Can't Add Patient! Disallowed implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to data type money, table 'TblName', column 'pTotalDue'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query*

how can I CONVERT it? could someone tell me how to do it?

here is my codes :

```
Private Function INSERT() As String
        Dim SQLcon As New SqlConnection
        Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader
        Try
            SQLcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=#####;Initial Catalog=#####;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=#####;Password=#####"
            Dim SQLcmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Patients" & _
                                         "(pIDNo,pLName,pFName,pMI,pSex,pStatus,pTelNo,pDocID,pAddr,pStreet,pBarangay,pCity,pProvince,pLNameKIN,pFNameKIN,pMIKIN,pRelationKIN,pTotalDue)" & _
                                         "VALUES(@pIDNo,@pLName,@pFName,@pMI,@pSex,@pStatus,@pTelNo,@pDocID,@pAddr,@pStreet,@pBarangay,@pCity,@pProvince,@pLNameKIN,@pFNameKIN,@pMIKIN,@pRelationKIN,@totaldue)", SQLcon)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIDNo", txtPNumber.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLName", txtLname.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFName", txtFname.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pMI", txtMI.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pSex", txtPatientSex.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pStatus", txtStatus.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pTelNo", txtPatientTelNo.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDocID", txtPatientDoctor.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pAddr", txtStreetNumber.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pStreet", txtStreetName.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBarangay", txtBarangay.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCity", txtCity.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pProvince", txtProvince.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLnameKIN", txtKinLname.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFnameKIN", txtKinFname.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pMIKIN", txtKinMI.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pRelationKIN", txtRelationToPatient.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totaldue", txtTotalDue.Text)
            SQLcon.Open()
            MsgBox("Patient Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured, Can't Add Patient!" & ex.Message)
        Finally
            SQLcon.Close()
        End Try
        Return ""
    End Function
```

BTW the version of SQL SERVER that I'm currently using is 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totaldue", txtTotalDue.Text)
```

to this:

```
SQLcmd.Parameters.Add("@totaldue", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Decimal.Parse(txtTotalDue.Text)
```

Comment: ok sir Tahbaza I will try it and tell you what will be the result.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but I have another question for my table on my program...,
I entered 200, but the result were, '200.00' on SQL SERVER but on my table is '200.0000' can I manipulate that result same to the result on SQL SERVER?

Comment: 200 is the same as 200.0000.  By choosing a money datatype for your column in your database table you've explicitly chosen the size and precision of your field.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882(v=sql.90).aspx for details.

Comment: so it's ok that the displayed value is 200.0000 rather that 200.00?

Comment: Can I manipulate the value displayed on table in VB winforms? I really want to reduce that result into 200.00 and not 200.0000

Comment: Format the value for display in the user interface as you wish after you fetch the value later, yes.

Comment: I'm kinda newbie where exactly will I manipulate the FORMAT of that certain value? and by the way I'm sorry I'm not using Table it's ListView...

Comment: You haven't said what language you're using in your application, but that's where you should format your data for display purposes.  If you're using .NET look at the `String.Format` function, examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm using VB winforms, is it different from .NET? I'm kinda confuse!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24542/discussion-between-danjor-and-tahbaza)